# Send Post var to Jquery modale popup

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am a beginner with Jquery,  I try to do some simple example to practice, 
In this example, I  am trying to send POST var from php form to Jquery modale popup that I found on the internet.

My problem is, I can't send my form var to my modale popup, when I click on submit  link to send my php form,

the popup appears without var in my case $name.

Here my codes :

**[Index.php](http://pastebin.com/uKzeL5Hi):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<form method = "POST" id = "formm" name="form1" action="recep.php" > 

<input type="text" name="nom"/> <br>

<a href="#?w=500" rel="popup_name" class="poplight" name="nom" onclick="openwindow(this)";">test</a><br>

</form>
```

**And finaly my [script.js](http://pastebin.com/5NBpY6nW)**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Trouver la pop-up correspondante
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Retrouver la largeur dans le href

    //Récupérer les variables depuis le lien
    var query= popURL.split('?');
    var dim= query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //La première valeur du lien

    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({
        'width': Number(popWidth)
    })
    .prepend('');

    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    $('#' + popID).css({
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    $('body').append(''); 
    //Apparition du fond - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) 
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();

    return false;
});

$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //Au clic sur le bouton ou sur le calque...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove(); 
    });
    return false;
}); 

});
});
```

**[recep.php](http://pastebin.com/Qbd5araz)**

```
<div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">
    <h2>Developpez.com</h2>
    <p>Soh Tanaka est traduit sur dev.com.<?php  if (isset($_POST['nom'])) { $nom = $_POST['nom']; echo 'la var est'.$nom; } ?></p>
</div>
```

I think i must add submit() condition to my script.js, beacause when i click on my link Jquery select only the href but he don't submit the form.

Any idea ?? :(

Thank you !!!

Comment: please include your code in the question

Comment: hi andres, i can not find the way why include my code here, this is why i inserted this two link, sorry missing php code : http://pastebin.com/Qbd5araz  many thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

It looks that trying to send a form but you don't submit it and the values you're trying to get on your recep.php are on an anchor that doesn't get send! Also, both input and anchor have the name="nom". You also have two functions called when the anchor is clicked. So there's a lot of things going on that you want to separate.

First you should decide if you're using jQuery ,javascript or both to call whatever function/s you need. 
If you're using Jquery, you'll need a way to call the element/s when the page loads by using

```
$('.whateverClass').click(function() { etc });
```

In this case I would use a class or id attribute. 
If you're using onclick you're going to call a javascript function. In this case you should pass all the parameters you want as an array

```
onclick="callTheFunction(this , '{put an array here with what you want?}')"
```

So this anchor will be at the bottom of the form but won't be part of the form. That's ok because you don't want to submit the form... You want to get all pars from the form and then ajax the values to the server using jQuery or javascript hhtp post/get request.

since you want to use jQuery, do something like

```
<input type="text" name="nameField" id="nameInput" /> <br>
<a href="#?w=500" rel="popup_name" id="popLight">test</a> <br>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.popLight').click(function() {

        //Get the form input value
        var nameInput = $('#nameInput').val(); 

        //Get the anchor attributes
        var href = $('#popLight').attr('href');

        //Do your stuff with the attr parameters, if you really need this here
        //...

        //Send your stuff to the server
        $.post("recep.php", { pars: "Your pars here"},
               function(receivedData) {
               //open whatever you want with the html from the server
                $('#whateverId').html('receivedData');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

To use a form to retrieve values, just id the form and call it from the function 
    var $input = $('#form :input').val();